# Extract data from Json: Error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=shooter.online.warplanes&hl=en'
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')
dt=json.loads(script.get_text())
```

> **Error :
> File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value**

Comment: I think the issue is to do with not receiving valid JSON, and the JSON parser doesn't accept this.

Comment: I think you receive invalid JSON. Paste the output of script.get_text() into any of JSON validators in the web. e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=shooter.online.warplanes&hl=en'
script = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find('script', type='application/ld+json')
print(json.loads(script.string)["name"])
```

Output:

```
Sky Combat: war planes online simulator PVP
```